# How to generate url changing wrt date?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract, unzip & read data from this url (https://www1.ukp.com/content/historical/2020/MAY/cm29MAY2020bhav.csv.zip
) on every working day. I manually edit the url  everyday . Is there any way to automate it in python

```
!wget https://www.ukp.com/content/historical/2020/MAY/cm29MAY2020bhav.csv.zip   

!unzip cm29MAY2020bhav.csv.zip   

cm3a = pd.read_csv('cm29MAY2020bhav.csv.zip',engine='python')
```

Comment: Please read this post - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This might be helpful in asking the question in a way so that others may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date.strftime` to generate the URL.

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().strftime("https://www1.ukp.com/content/historical/%Y/%B/cm%d%B%Ybhav.csv.zip")
'https://www1.ukp.com/content/historical/2020/June/cm01June2020bhav.csv.zip'
```

If case sensitivity matters, you'll have to break it up into a few pieces. For example:

```
>>> year, month, day = date.today().strftime("%Y-%B-%d").split("-")
>>> month = month.upper()
>>> f'https://www1.ukp.com/content/historical/{year}/{month}/cm{day}{month}{year}bhav.csv.zip'
'https://www1.ukp.com/content/historical/2020/JUNE/cm01JUNE2020bhav.csv.zip'
```

Comment: awesome sir its working flawless. sir how can i use the output url in 1. wget , 2. unzip & read_csv  , i have pasted code along with by question above